# React Testing Library + Material UI DropDown

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm having some problems that I'm not able to test the MUI dropdown. I'm getting this error: `Unable to find an accessible element with the role "option" and name "/ninica/i"`

I have an example code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-material-ui-dropdown-5knbgu

My test:

```js
test("select", () => {
  render(<App />);

  // Get and click in the dropdown
  const dropdownButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /dog name ​/i });
  fireEvent.click(dropdownButton);

  // Get and click in the dropdown item
  const dropdownItem = screen.getByRole("option", { name: /ninica/i });
  fireEvent.click(dropdownItem);
});
```

I already try to use `getByTestId` but have the same result, can't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
test("select", async () => {
  render(<App />);

  // Get and click in the dropdown
  const dropdownButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /dog name ​/i });
  fireEvent.click(dropdownButton);

  // Wait for dropdown item and click it
  const dropdownItem = await screen.findByTestId("name-item-2");
  fireEvent.click(dropdownItem);
});
```

There are some ms in between the click and the apearance on the screen of the element, so you have declare your function as `async` and to `await`  for your element to appear (and use findBy instead of getBy in order to work as async).

you can read more about testing-library async methods [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time, but I tried, and it’s not working, keeps showing error. I already update the project if you can and want to check out :)

(Sorry, I didn’t reply sooner, I didn’t check )

Comment: Hello! Is working for me: https://ibb.co/jZykCFw

Comment: But I think `codesanbox` is not the best in properly giving the tests results due to catching, so I would advise you to  try on your local machine as well (or at least try to access the link in an incognito window)

Comment: Ohhh, yap, it's now working for me too 

Answer (score 5):

First of all, for component interaction, prefer the use of `userEvent` instead `fireEvent` as `testing-library` describes:

> The built-in fireEvent is a utility to easily dispatch events. It dispatches exactly the events you tell it to and just those - even if those exact events never had been dispatched in a real interaction in a browser.
> user-event on the other hand dispatches the events like they would happen if a user interacted with the document. That might lead to the same events you previously dispatched per fireEvent directly, but it also might catch bugs that make it impossible for a user to trigger said events. This is why you should use user-event to test interaction with your components.

You can check more about it [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro#difference-to-fireevent).

Related to test not find `option` role, it´s because the element take some milliseconds to appear on screen and because of that your test should be `async` and you need to use `await` and `findBy` query to succeed in the test:

```js
import { render, screen, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

test("select", async () => {
  render(<App />);

  const dropdownButton = screen.getByRole("button");

  userEvent.click(dropdownButton);

  const dropdownItem = await screen.findByRole("option", { name: /ninica/i });

  userEvent.click(dropdownItem);

  const typographyEl = await screen.findByText(/Chosen name: ninica/i);

  expect(typographyEl).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

You can check more about `async/await` and `findBy` query [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#findby-queries).

You can also check the difference of queries [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#types-of-queries).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time, the help and for the references.
I already update the project if you can and want to check out :) 
(Sorry, I didn’t reply sooner, I didn’t check )

Answer (score 1):

In my case element.click() event does not trigger dropdown open, so I had to come up with code changes in my component where I can open it via {open} and bind to select itself here is how I have done it.

```
  import React from 'react';
  import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
  import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
  import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
  import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
  import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    
    export default function ControlledOpenSelect() {
      const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
      const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    
      const handleChange = (event) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <FormControl >
            <Select
              open={open}
              onClick={()=> setOpen(!open)}
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              <MenuItem value="">
                <em>None</em>
              </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

in any testing now click event triggers open of select, Not sure if it's an bad pratice, but yeah it works :)